# Apply a function to each element of a 3D, 2 channel Keras tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a model that processes 2 input 3D images of the same size, `A` and `B`, for use in a more classical function to attempt to increase performance of this function. In order to properly train the model I need to apply the function to the result of each run. The function itself takes 2 values, which correspond to the values in `A` and `B` at the same coordinate `p`. This result is to be stored in a 3D image, `C`, of the same size as `A` and `B` at point `p`. Classical implementations of this would perform a `for` loop over all the coordinates and apply the function for each pair. Unfortunately, this approach does not work for training a Keras model as the output of the function has to feed back to the weights of the previous layers.

```
Input -(A, B)-> Model -(A', B')-> Function(A'[p], B'[p]) -(C[p])-> Result
```

I have attempted to write a custom Keras layer for this. This layer accepts a 4D tensor `(channel, z, y, x)` and should return a tensor with shape `(1, z, y, x)`.

Currently this looks like:

```py
# imports

def function(x: [float, float]) -> float:
    # a -> x[0], b -> x[1]
    # Calculate
    return c

class CustomLayer(Layer):
    # ... __init__ and build
    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        # All samples, channel n ([::][n])
        # We stack the tensors in such a way because map_fn() maps the top most axis to the function.
        # This way a tensor of shape (n_voxels, 2) is created and the values are delivered in pairs to the function
        map_input = K.stack([K.flatten(inputs[::][0]), K.flatten(inputs[::][1]), axis=1])
        result = K.map_fn(lambda x: function(x), map_input)
        result = K.reshape(result, K.constant([-1, 1, inputs.shape[2], inputs.shape[3], inputs.shape[4]], dtype=tf.int32))
        return result
```

Unfortunately, this method has severely slowed down the training. Whereas the model *without* the custom layer at the end took around 45 minutes to train per epoch, the model *with* the custom layer takes about 120 *hours* per epoch.

The model and the function on their own can perform the required task with a significant error, however I wanted to see if I could combine the two for better results.

---

The real-life use in my case is the decomposition of materials from [Dual Energy CT](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5447632/). You can calculate the fraction of materials for each voxel by assuming 3 known materials `mat1`, `mat2`, `mat3` and an unknown sample `sample`.

With some calculations you can then decompose this unknown sample into fractions of each known material `f1`, `f2`, `f3` (`f1` + `f2` + `f3` == 1.0). We are only interested in `f3`, so the calculations for the other fractions have been omitted.

Actual code:

```py
"""
DECT Decomposition Layer
"""

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Layer
from keras.constraints import MinMaxNorm


def _intersect(line1_start, line1_end, line2_start, line2_end, ):
    """
    Find the intersection point between 2 lines
    """
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection

    # Tensorflow's tensors need a little more lines to unpack
    x1 = line1_start[0]
    y1 = line1_start[1]
    x2 = line1_end[0]
    y2 = line1_end[1]
    x3 = line2_start[0]
    y3 = line2_start[1]
    x4 = line2_end[0]
    y4 = line2_end[1]

    px = (x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) * (x3 - x4) - (x1 - x2) * (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4)
    px /= (x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4)
    py = (x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4)
    py /= (x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4)

    return K.stack([px, py])


def _decomp(sample, mat1, mat2, mat3):
    """
    Decomposition of a sample into 1 fraction of material 3
    """
    # Calculate the sample lines' ends
    sample3 = sample + (mat2 - mat3)

    # Calculate the intersection points between the sample lines and triangle sides
    intersect3 = _intersect(sample, sample3, mat1, mat2)

    # Find out how far along the sample line the intersection is
    f3 = tf.norm(sample - intersect3) / tf.norm(sample - sample3)

    return f3


class DectDecompoLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, mat1, mat2, mat3, **kwargs):
        self.mat1 = K.constant(mat1)
        self.mat2 = K.constant(mat2)
        self.mat3 = K.constant(mat3)

        super(DectDecompoLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(DectDecompoLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        map_input = K.stack([K.flatten(inputs[::][0]), K.flatten(inputs[::][1])], axis=1)
        result = K.map_fn(lambda x: _decomp(x, self.mat1, self.mat2, self.mat3), map_input)
        result = K.reshape(result, K.constant([-1, 1, inputs.shape[2], inputs.shape[3], inputs.shape[4]], dtype=tf.int32))
        return result

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0], 1, input_shape[2], input_shape[3], input_shape[4]
```

Comment: You need to make your function a tensor function using backend functions. (Don't use loops) It's not possible to answer without knowing your function.

Comment: which tensorflow version are you using?

Comment: @DanielMöller I am not using a loop. I am mapping a list of (`A`, `B`) pairs to the function. I'll update the question with the real code, but it's not very different from what I have described.

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat TF1.13.1. Unfortunately, I have no control over the version on the PC. Would you reckon this will work better on a TF2.1 machine?

Comment: I am not sure but look like your custom layer and function does not connect well to perform efficiently,in tesnorflow 2.0 has `@tf.function` to connect the outer function to the graph

Comment: Are they two "separate" inputs? Tensor A and Tensor B? Or are they two "samples" in a single input?

Comment: @DanielMöller They are the same input. A and B can be treated as two channels of the same image.

Comment: Ok.... another one.... how are you intersecting "lines" when you say the funcion is from voxel p to voxel p?

Comment: Can you describe the full shape of the inputs? Before any separation?

Comment: @DanielMöller I am treating value `A[p]` as the `x` coordinate and value `B[p]` as the `y` coordinate. The known materials are also treated as different `(x,y)` coordinates. These coordinates can be used to create line segments with which I can intersect. The exact reasoning why is not important for the question, I think.

The input for the custom layer is expected to be `(None, 2, 32, 128, 128)` for my use-case.

Comment: I see, can you also share the shapes of `mat1`, `mat2`  and `mat3`?

Comment: `(2,)` for all three. This shouldn't be an issue since I only pass `(2,)` sample points to the function, right? Either way, I can grow the `mat` arrays to match the `inputs` if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. The first thing that is very strange is that you are taking "samples", not "channels".

The command `inputs[::]` returns exactly `inputs`, and `inputs[::][0]` is equal to `inputs[0]`.

So, you are training only two samples, no matter  how big your batch size is.

That said, all you need is something like:

- Assuming `inputs` with shape `(batch, 2, size, size, size)`
- Assuming `matN` with shape `(1, 2, size, size, size)`, exactly, or `(batch, 2, size, size, size)`

```
def call(self, inputs, **kwargs): #shape (batch, 2, size, size, size)
    sample3 = inputs + (self.mat2 - self.mat3) 

    #all shapes (batch, size, size, size)
    x1 = inputs[:,0]
    y1 = inputs[:,1]
    x2 = sample3[:,0]
    y2 = sample3[:,1]

    #all shapes (1, size, size, size) or (batch, size, size, size)
    x3 = self.mat1[:,0]
    y3 = self.mat2[:,1]
    x4 = self.mat2[:,0]
    y4 = self.mat2[:,1]


    #all shapes (batch, size, size, size)
    px = (x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) * (x3 - x4) - (x1 - x2) * (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4)
    px /= (x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4)
    py = (x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4)
    py /= (x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4)

    #proceed with the rest
```

Warning, you may have division by zero for parallel lines.

I recommend some kind of `K.switch` like:

```
denominator = (x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4)
K.switch(
    K.less(K.abs(denominator), K.epsilon()), 
    denominator + K.sign(denominator)*K.epsilon(), 
    denominator)
px /= denominator
```

Comment: I will give this a try when I get back to my work PC tomorrow.

RE: parallel lines. I was aware of the risk that such a thing could occur. However,  due to the nature of the points, it is not a risk in my current situation. I am planning on doing sanity checks when I finalize the code, though.

Comment: Ok, for `mat.shape == (2,)`, you should `K.reshape(mat, (1,2,1,1,1))`

Comment: I have implemented your suggestion and it seems to work. Unfortunately, I can't properly test it as I get the following error: `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dect_decompo_layer_1 to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (6, 32, 128, 128)`. I have checked the shape of `f3`, which is `(?, 1, 32, 128, 128)`. Somewhere in there, Keras/TF seems to lose the channel dimension. Adding a `Reshape` layer only moves the error to that layer instead.

Comment: Your model output doesn't match your `y` data, just reshape one of them.

Comment: It was the `__len__` still reporting the shape as `(?, 1, 32, 128, 128)` while it should've been `(?, 32, 128, 128)`. This is still a little strange, as I already reshaped the `f3` tensor to include the channel axis, but maybe Keras likes to drop axes of size 1. Either way, this seems to be working much faster than what I had earlier.